# Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>(A new kind of riddle)</sup>*
I ordered 5 Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat only - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | weak |
| E | cyst |
| I | succeed |
| O | secured |
| Y | letter |

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Today's Vowelburger comes with:

> A **W** bun and an **N** bun...

Just check out our menu:

> A - "weak", i.e **WAN**
>  E - "cyst", i.e. **WEN** (a [sebaceous cyst](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wen))
>  I - "succeed", i.e. **WIN**
>  O - "secured", i.e. **WON**
>  Y - "letter", i.e. **WYN** ([an old English runic letter](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wyn))

So, what's for dessert?! :)

Comment: More burgers, probably...

Comment: 20% of a [free folk ice giant](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Wun_Weg_Wun_Dar_Wun).

Comment: @Flater 60% :-)

Answer (score 32):

Your "vowelburgers" are:

> wan [weak]; wen [[cyst](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wen)]; win [succeed]; won [secured]; wyn [[letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynn), more commonly spelled "wynn"].

Comment: This answer was 13 seconds earlier, so I wasn't entirely decided on whom to give the checkmark; in the end, I awarded it based on aesthetic considerations (of the answer's presentation). Great job solving the puzzle, though :)