# Another Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>You can find the first Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle)</sup>*
I ordered 5 Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat only - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | receptacle |
| E | adjure |
| I | momentous |
| O | mire |
| U | enthusiasm |

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Today's Vowelburger starts with the receptacle

> bag

adjure

> beg

momentous

> big

mire

> bog

and ends in enthusiasm

> bug - as an obsession

Comment: Wow. Literally just been beaten to two write-ups in two minutes! Perhaps this is a sign I should get back on with work...! +1

Comment: @Stiv Perhaps, perhaps not :)

Comment: @Stiv I'm actually beaten by two seconds, this answer appeared as I wanted to click "Post Your Answer" lol.

Comment: @Tom Out of the five burgers, which one gave you the idea so fast?!

Comment: @Avi - the enthusiasm!