# A filling Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word

I ordered 5 Vowelburgers™ with buns, cheese and meat - help me identify each one  from the menu!

| Cheese | Vowelburger |
| --- | --- |
| A | bag |
| E | bite |
| I | cream |
| O | swelling |
| U | sprite |

<sub>Inspired by Avi’s [Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle)</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Today's Vowelburger comes with:

> A **P** bun and a **K** bun and with meat **C**.

I think they are

> A - PACK
>  E - PECK
>  I - PICK (like "cream of the crop")
>  O - POCK
>  U - [PUCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puck_(folklore))

Comment: I was thinking the same. Why I and U though?

Comment: Wow, that's a fast answer!

Comment: @KaranAtree Cream means "the very best of a group of people or things" like "cream of the crop". I've also added a link for U

Comment: Got it. Kudos on the great (and speedy) answer!

Comment: Since the OP stated, cheese and meat along with buns, in contrast to only meat (as in the original puzzle), you ought to split your two-letter buns to a meat and a bun (+1)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Thank you, I didn't notice that, edited now.

Comment: No problem, @hexomino :)

Comment: !!!! Vowels are meat, cheese is rot13(P)

Comment: @Avi Perhaps this is a discussion for you and Tom, he's clearly labelled the vowel column as "Cheese" so I am just following that.

Comment: @Avi - I switched to cheese on top, so say cheese for the vowel :)