# I Spy a Vowelburger Riddle™

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>You can find the first Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle)</sup>*
I ordered 5 Vowelburgers™ with buns, lettuce, and meat - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | masculine |
| E | chant |
| I | race |
| O | spy |
| U | beast |

Comment: Just when I was about to write my own :)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Don't worry, you can do that after you solve this one :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Today's Vowelburger comes with:

> An **M** bun, plenty of **L**ettuce and an **E** bun to finish off...

Choose from:

> A - "masculine", i.e **MALE**
>  E - "chant", i.e. **[MELE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mele)**
>  I - "race", i.e. **[MILE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile_run)**
>  O - "spy", i.e. **MOLE**
>  U - "beast", i.e. **MULE**

Bon appetit! :)

Comment: Help! My Vowelburger's™ on fire from this lightning fast solve!

Comment: @Avi Then may I recommend a cooling sorbet to follow? ;-)

Comment: Just another Vowelburger™, please