# An Inappropriate Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>You can find the first Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle)</sup>*
I ordered 5 plain Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | screen |
| E | rally |
| I | die |
| O | father |
| U | baby |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today's Vowelburger has:

> Two **P** buns...

We're serving:

> A - "screen", i.e **PAP** (pap smear)
>  E - "rally", i.e. **PEP** (increase peppiness)
>  I - "die", i.e. **PIP** (on dice)
>  O - "father", i.e. **POP** (as popposed to "papa")
>  U - "baby", i.e. **PUP** (baby animals)

I'm going to dig in for sure!

Comment: Exactly! Great, fast response.