# A demanding Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle)</sup>*
I ordered 5 plain Vowelburgers™ with only buns and meat - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | MJ |
| E | sea |
| I | sum |
| O | demand |
| U | flower |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a ---

> **B**x**D** Burger
>  - **BAD** - Album by MJ
>  - **BED** - Sea bed
>  - **BID** - You bid a sum
>  - **BOD** - [Biological Oxygen Demand](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemical_oxygen_demand)
>  - **BUD** - Flower bud