# A Full Spread of Vowelburgers™

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, pattern, letters

<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>

I ordered some Vowelburgers™ abroad, but every menu had a printing error, so the restaurant just got rid of them. Regardless, they had something for everyone, offering the normal spread plus the unconventional "W" and "Y" burgers. Naturally, I decided to sample one of each burger, which all came with buns, meat*, and cheese. What were they?

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | detach |
| E | disfigure |
| I | detain |
| O | settle |
| U | govern |
| W** | move |
| Y | replace |

*The "Y" burger is vegetarian.
**Only available at their British location.

Hint:

> The printing error was that the last page of each menu was a bit off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that today's Vowelburger comes with

> **B** and **D** buns and **N** cheese

Examples (thanks to TruVortex_07 for getting "W" in the comments)

> **BAND** (not sure about this one but possibly referring to bands which act in a detaching manner, like band gaps in an electron).
>  **BEND** = disfigure.
>  **BIND** = detain.
>  **BOND** = settle (one definition of bond is to lay bricks in an overlapping pattern so as to form a strong structure.).
>  **BUND** = govern (possibly referring to the Deutscher Bund - the German confederation).
>  [**BWND**](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bath+Wilts+%26+North+Dorset+Gliding+Club/@51.1312084,-2.2402169,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x1bcb5963ad32c0fd!8m2!3d51.1312084!4d-2.2402169) = **B**ath **W**ilts & **N**orth **D**orset Gliding Club, where they "move".
>  [**BYND**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Meat) refers to *Beyond Meat*, a Los Angeles-based producer of plant-based meat substitutes (**replacing** the meat)
>  Original Guess for **BWND** = move, I think this one is the typo as **BWNED**, in Welsh, means "Let's go".

---

#### Notes from OP

The printing error explained:

> The last page of each menu (last page = last letter) was off a bit ("menu" → "ment") so they got rid of them (i.e., removed "ment" from each of the Vowelburgers™). This means they were originally detachment, disfigurement, detainment, settlement, government, movement, and replacement.

E, I, U, and Y are mostly unaffected by this change, but A, O and W's solutions make more sense after this transformation:

> A: A "detachment" of people, units, etc. can also be called a "band".
>  O: A "settlement" between two parties can also be called a "bond".
>  W: A synonym of "movement" is "flight", which occurs at the BWND.

Finally,

> W and Y are unconventional both in the sense that they are only sometimes vowels, but their solutions also aren't technically words: BWND is the abbreviation for the Bath Wilts & North Dorset Gliding Club, and BYND is the stock symbol for Beyond Meat.

This puzzle was inspired by:

> [A demanding Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94049/a-demanding-vowelburger-riddle), when I noticed that "N" could be added to make new words, and after verifying that "bund" was a word, I ran from there.

Comment: rot13(OJAQ pbhyq or [guvf](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bath+Wilts+%26+North+Dorset+Gliding+Club/@51.1312084,-2.2402169,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x1bcb5963ad32c0fd!8m2!3d51.1312084!4d-2.2402169) orpnhfr tyvqvat vf n sbez bs zbirzrag)

Comment: You're almost there, except the "getting rid of every menu" isn't what you think and will make the clues for A, O, and W fit better

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, and it feels kind of nitpicky to leave it open (especially since it's been two weeks; I forgot about it lol). Would it be OK with you hexomino if I accepted this answer and added some explanation/wrap-up to it? E, I, U, and Y are correct (as well as @TruVortex_07's answer for W) and O is technically correct, but there's another part to the puzzle that would change it. I can try to add more hints if you'd prefer that/if that's better practice, but I'm not sure how helpful they would be.

Comment: @samm82 I don't mind, however you'd like to do it. I don't think I will get much further on my own. They're not acronyms, are they?

Comment: Nope - W and Y are the only "unconventional" ones