# A double-patty Vowelburger™ riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's [Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle)</sup>*
My new fry chef came up with the Double Vowelburger, which has a top bun, cheese, two patties and a bottom bun! She's very economical with ingredients, so each vowel A-E-I-O-U appears only one time as a top and bottom patty, and no burgers have the same top and bottom patty. But she's also a little absentminded, and one of the burgers has a different bottom bun. Can you help me figure out what's in these things?

| Top Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | braid |
| E | fold |
| I | worked |
| O | splash |
| U | fruit |

Comment: The changing top patties were decent, but the mismatched bottom bun must have gone bad, it left a sour taste for the whole meal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today's Double Vowelburgers come with:

> A **P** bun, **L** cheese, two vowel patties and a **T** bun (with one stray *D* bun thrown into the mix...).

Choose from the following:

> AI patty combo - "braid", i.e **PLAIT**
>  EA patty combo - "fold", i.e. **PLEAT**
>  IE patty combo - "worked", i.e. **PLIED** (one's trade)
>  OU patty combo - "splash", i.e. **[PLOUT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plout)** (sudden heavy rainfall, usually in Scotland)
>  UO patty combo - "fruit", i.e. **[PLUOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluot)** (a hybrid 'interspecific plum')

Apologies for the stray bottom bun, sirs - please accept that one on the house...