# Namely, A Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>You can find other Vowelburgers™ Riddles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger+is%3Aquestion). Find the first one [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle?noredirect=1&lq=1).</sup>*
I ordered 5 Vowelburgers™ with buns, tomatoes, and meat - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | Hamilton |
| E | Crystal |
| U | Mario |
| O | Luna |
| Y | Atlas |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today's Vowelburger comes with:

> An **M** bun, **T**omatoes and an **H** bun...

Your options today are:

> A - "Hamilton", i.e **[MATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)** (Hamiltonian cycles, named after the Irish mathematician, [William Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rowan_Hamilton))
>  E - "Crystal", i.e. **METH** (the drug)
>  U - "Mario", i.e. **[MUTH](https://www.mariowiki.com/Muth)** (a mammoth-like enemy in the Mario games)
>  O - "Luna", i.e. **[MOTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_moth)** (a variety of moth)
>  Y - "Atlas", i.e. **[MYTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(mythology))** (the titan from Greek mythology)

Enjoy!

Comment: No link provided for E for obvious reasons! ;-)

Comment: I figured out the solution just by reading your comment

Comment: @melfnt Wow, didn't think that would turn out to be a spoiler!

Comment: rot13(pelfgny, fbzrguvat jvgu R - sbe juvpu lbh pbhyq abg cebivqr n yvax). I'm also rot13(jngpuvat oernxvat orq)