# A Vegan Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

There's a restaurant that's heard that Vowelburger™ riddles don't satiate like they used to, so it's decided to start selling more sophisticated burgers.

The menu says they sell a ***False*** Vowelburger™, a ***Real*** Vowelburger™, and a ***Lookalike*** Vowelburger™. You know that each burger comes with three buns and two meat choices, in the order *bun-meat-bun-meat-bun*, with the same type and order of buns on each. Oddly, though, the menu won't tell you what the meats are...

| Meats | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ?, ? | False |
| ?, ? | Real |
| ?, ? | Lookalike |

But you're a Vowelburger™ veteran. Can you guess what the meats are without looking at the menu?

**Hint:**

> While the other two should be doable, I realized after posting that the clue for "Real" is extremely obscure. The connection comes from quantum mechanics, but even if you Google "real qubit" (which is what the term is), the term is so obscure that finding it will still require some digging. I realize this makes for a poor puzzle, so I apologize for that. I'll wait until tomorrow and then post the one term if no one finds it.

**Bonus:**

As a marketing ploy, the restaurant's strategy team was also thinking of instituting a ***Secret*** Vowelburger™. Can you tell them why it would be a bad idea because the CIA would come knocking?

<sup>P.S. You can find other Vowelburgers™ Riddles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger+is%3Aquestion). Find the first one [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle?noredirect=1&lq=1). Note that buns = consonants and meats = vowels still.</sup>

Comment: +10 for variety, if I could :)

Comment: This feels like a good variation on the theme...

Comment: I will say upfront that I think this is very hard.

Comment: I thought it would be rot13(IRANY sbe SNYFR (orgenlvat qhgl guebhtu pbeehcgvba) naq IVALY sbe n jbbq ybbxnyvxr), but I couldn't find a 3rd one.

Comment: I just realized, after doing some Googling, that the "real" clue is extremely obscure - sorry about that. I am adding a hint to hopefully make this more doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the answers are

> REBUT (provide evidence that a thing is **false**),
>  REBIT (a **real** analogue of the qubit; see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435787/are-there-any-physical-realizations-of-a-rebit-a-qubit-with-real-coefficients-f)), and
>  ROBOT (a **lookalike** human, at least in some cases).

Comment: I should make it explicit that this was done _after_ anodyne posted the hint.

Comment: Might be it, I think :)

Comment: @anodyne You missed an opportunity for a Moroccan tagine burger here ;-)

Comment: @Stiv I love it. :) I had that one in for awhile but couldn't come up with anything to go with the false/real theme so I took it out :/