# Vowelburger™ Double Supreme #1

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
The local Vowelburgers™ restaurant added a twist to compete its sales with the other branches. They started making double patty burgers where the patties need not be the same.

To make it more interesting they only have the one-word description and you should discover what the two vowel patties are in each burger in addition to the buns. Below is their first menu:

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ?? | free |
| ?? | zit |
| ?? | 100 |
| ?? | 2 |

Can you help me identify each one from the description on the menu?

Comment: Are the patties at least next to each other?

Comment: @North Yes indeed they are, just two consonant buns with two vowel patties.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The buns are brought to you today by the letters:

> **B** and **L**

and the patties:

> **BAIL** - money paid to escape imprisonment
>  **BEAL** -  a [pustule](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Beal)
>  **BOIL** - water boils at $100^\circ$
>  **BOOL** - a Boolean variable is either true or false

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I hear the next menu would have even more items, hope you are up for it ;)

Answer (score 12):

I think it may be:

> bail - free someone
>  boil - similar to a zit or pustule
>  beal - William Beal started the 100 year seed experiment (ok, a bit  of a stretch)
>  bool - 2 as in boolean, or base 2

Comment: Lbh tbg gur ohetref evtug! Ohg pbhyq lbh purpx gur qrsvavgvba bs rnpu bs gurz bapr zber naq erguvax gur beqre?