# Vowelburger™ Double Supreme #2

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
After the success of their [first Double Supreme menu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94590/18418), the local Vowelburgers™ restaurant decided to increase the variety.

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ?? | insects |
| ?? | unfair |
| ?? | startup |
| ?? | long |
| ?? | young |

Can you help me identify each one from the description on the menu?

---

*A Double Supreme Vowelburger™ is a word formed with with two consonant buns sandwiching two vowel patties.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting with what Rand al'Thor found out

> B and S [1]

with the words being

> BEES (nice honey insects) [1]
>  BIAS (favoring a side) [1]
>  BIOS (what executes when you start up a pc)
>  BOAS (long snakes)
>  BOYS (young men) [1]

[1] credit to [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94655/64500) for these

Comment: Great! Although I’m not sure whom to accept as both of you got one wrong in different places, the first to provide a complete answer with explanation will get accepted.

Comment: Ok since you said we both got one wrong i will go with bows and bois being wrong because i'd rather accept a Y as vowel (as a german i have a hard time doing so) than a W

Comment: I would still like if Rand got the check because he found out the majority of the riddle but i'm not sure what customs here dictate

Comment: What answer to accept is entirely at the asker's discretion; usually they pick the "best" answer, using whatever criteria they feel to be best. As I've mentioned [previously](/q/62071/#comment189458_62084), some reward the answer that contains the most significant contribution(s), and some choose to reward the answer which is most complete. Ideally, these are the same answer—the person with the greatest contribution also adds the contributions of others, with attribution, to make a single canonical answer.

Answer (score 10):

The consonants are

> B and S

with the words being

> BEES (insects)
>  BIAS (unfair)
>  BIOS (computer startup) <sup>[thanks to [Konstantin Pfennig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94656/5373) for this one - I don't know much about computers]</sup>
>  BOWS (longbows)
>  BOYS (young)

Note:

> here you seem to be counting W and Y as vowels :-)

Feedback section:

> it was partly lucky chance that helped me to get this quickly. The first clue made me think of BUGS - which doesn't fit, of course, since it has only one vowel - but that meant B and S were in my mind when I was looking at the second clue, and unfair leads fairly quickly to BIAS. I say partly lucky because I *was* fairly sure at least that the last letter would be S just from the first clue.

Comment: Great as always, al’Thor :) But Konstantin got what you missed. I’ll accept the first to provide a complete answer. Happy puzzling!

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I've edited my answer to include (crediting Konstantin) the 3rd clue that he found. We disagree on the 4th and 5th clues, but I'm still more convinced by my answers than his for those.

Comment: Sorry mate, Konstantin got all the intended answers. Nevertheless, you do get credit!