# Vowelburger™ Double Supreme #3

Tags: riddle, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
The local Vowelburgers™ restaurant increased the variety of their Double Supreme burgers yet again.

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ?? | fish |
| ?? | music |
| ?? | vegetable |
| ?? | sea |
| ?? | walk |
| ?? | illness |

Can you help me identify each one from the description on the menu?

---

*A Double Supreme Vowelburger™ is a word formed with with two consonant buns sandwiching two vowel patties. Previous Double Supreme menus: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94590/18418) and [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94654/18418)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe we have a

> BT Burger

With...

> fish **bait**
>  music **beat**
>  vegetable: **beet**
>  sea **boat**
>  a **boot** made for walking
>  a **bout** with illness