# Vowelburgers™ Chef’s Special #1

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, letters

*<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418). Hope you enjoyed our [Double Supreme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94698/18418) variants.</sup>*
We at Vowelburgers™ are finding more and more ways to bring variety to the table. The chef’s choice of the day consists of a vowel patty, a complementary cheese layer and a special bun. The variety lies in the other bun and an add-on.

| Bun + add-on | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ?? | deceive |
| ?? | red |
| ?? | hit |
| ?? | paste |
| ?? | dense |
| ?? | snap |

Can you help me identify each one from the description on the menu?

Comment: One or two vowel patties? (The grid has two ?'s but the text has it in singular).

Comment: @eyl327 The clues lie in the riddle. Try with the clues at hand. If still required, I may add a clarification hint tomorrow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, so as I understand it

> The vowel patty, the cheese and one bun are fixed and the other bun and an add-on are variable.

So I think the patty, cheese and special bun are

> **I**, **C** and **K**

and so our burgers are as follows

> TR**ICK** = deceive
>  BR**ICK** = red
>  FL**ICK** = hit
>  ST**ICK** = paste
>  TH**ICK** = dense
>  CL**ICK** = snap

Comment: We hope you enjoyed our service!