# Vowelburgers™ Chef’s Special #2

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, letters

*<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
The success of our [first Chef’s Special](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94962/18418) has inspired our chef to add even more variety to your favourite Vowelburgers™ menu. The chef’s choice of the day consists of a vowel patty, cheese, lettuce, and a special bun. The variety lies in the other bun.

| Bun | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ? | discharge |
| ? | disperse |
| ? | brake |
| ? | fish |
| ? | catches |
| ? | complain |
| ? | instrument |
| ? | twist |
| ? | cover |

Now here is the twist: Though the contents of the burgers are fixed, the order isn’t so. Also, the special bun can be either at the top or bottom.

Can you identify each one from the description on the menu?

Hint:

> Only two pairs are anagrams

Comment: I'm wondering about the forms of some provided words.  Based on the accepted answer, 'catches' makes sense, but it feels like 'complain', 'instrument', 'twist', and 'cover' should also end in -s.

Comment: Yes @hagfy, that was exactly what I had in mind initially but it seemed too obvious what the special bun would be in that case. The burger name need only to give a clue to what the contents are, not to describe it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the patty cheese and lettuce are

> P, R and A

and the special bun is

> S

Burgers

> discharge = **SPAR**K
>  disperse = **SPRA**Y
>  brake = **SPRA**G
>  fish = **SPRA**T
>  catches = T**RAPS**
>  complain =  C**ARPS**
>  instrument = H**ARPS**
>  twist =  W**ARPS**
>  cover = W**RAPS**

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for being a valuable customer. We hope to see you again soon.