# Vowelburgers™ Chef's Special #3

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, letters

*<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418). Hope you enjoyed our previous Chef's Specials: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94962/18418) and [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/95059/18418)</sup>*
Our chef went way ahead to prepare the biggest Vowelburger™ menu to date! There is a burger for every size. The chef's choice of the day consists of a vowel patty, cheese, lettuce, and a special bun. The variety lies in the other bun.

| Bun | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ? | diminutive |
| ? | tiny |
| ? | small |
| ? | normal |
| ? | medium |
| ? | big |
| ? | large |
| ? | roomy |
| ? | whopper |
| ? | full |

Not only are the *contents* of the chef's choice fixed, but their *order* is fixed as well. There are no anagrams in this menu; the other bun is strictly a consonant. It's amazing how the chef has brought so much variety with these constraints!

**Can you identify each one from the description on the menu?**

Comment: I assume this isn't a trick like they're all the same word with size prefixes? k for kilo, M for mega, G for giga, m for milli, n for nano, etc.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That’s actually not a bad idea but it would be awful for this riddle. Having said, the rest of the word wouldn’t make sense without the bun. If I state any more, I’d probably giving the answer away ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility:

> Variable first bun, I patty, G cheese, H lettuce, and T second bun.

The burgers are:

> [DIGHT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dight) (archaic word for dress or adorn), TIGHT, SIGHT, NIGHT, MIGHT, [BIGHT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bight) (a bay formed from a bend in the coast), LIGHT, RIGHT, [WIGHT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wight) (an unfortunate person or a ghost / supernatural being), FIGHT - the first bun matches the first letter of the description.

Comment: Congratulations! Hope you enjoyed our service!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the chef's choice is

> an I patty, L lettuce, L cheese, and an S special bun

---

> `diminutive - GILLS`
> `tiny - PILLS`
> `small - DILLS`
> `normal - BILLS`
> `medium - JILLS`
> `big - SILLS`
> `large - MILLS`
> `roomy - HILLS`
> `whopper - VILLS`
> `full - FILLS`

Comment: Nice try indeed, but could you explain how the burger name matches with the description?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I assume that means you're looking for there to be more of a connection than just the size of the objects?

Comment: Now you are heading along the right direction ;)

Comment: Here's a thought: rot13(Vs lbh rng rirelguvat ba gur zrah, lbh'yy cebonoyl unir znal VYYF.)  :)