# Vowelburger™ Triple Supreme

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418) and Ébe Isaac's [Double Supreme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94590/vowelburger-double-supreme-1) Riddle.</sup>
The local Vowelburgers™ has added yet another a twist. They started making triple patty burgers where the patties need not be the same.

Here is their new menu:

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ??? | exchange |
| ??? | money |
| ??? | feast |

Can you identify each type from the description on the menu?

*A Triple Supreme Vowelburger™ is a word formed with with two consonant buns sandwiching three vowel patties.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the very hungry, our Vowelburger Triple Supreme comes with:

> An **L** bun and an **S** bun...

Can you and your stomach conquer any of the following?

> "exchange", i.e **LIEUS** ([definition: "in lieu of"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lieu))
>  "money", i.e. **LOUIS** ([a French coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_d'or))
>  "feast", i.e. **LUAUS** ([a Hawaiian feast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C5%AB%CA%BBau))

Complete the challenge and win a free T-shirt!*

<sub>* *T-shirt prize is not real...*</sub>