# Vowelburger™ Triple Supreme #2

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418) and Ébe Isaac's [Double Supreme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94590/vowelburger-double-supreme-1) Riddle.</sup>
The local Vowelburgers™ [recently](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94736/vowelburger-triple-supreme) started making Triple Supremes with two consonant buns sandwiching three vowel patties.

Here is their second menu:

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ??? | floozy |
| ??? | head |
| ??? | angle |

Can you identify each type from the description on the menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to popular demand, our Vowelburger Triple Supreme range has been extended to include:

> A **Q** bun and an **N** bun...

Why not try one of the following:

> "floozy", i.e **QUEAN** ([definition: "an overly forward, impudent woman"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/quean))
>  "head", i.e. **QUEEN** (as in 'head of state')
>  "angle", i.e. **QUOIN** ([definition: "an external angle of a wall or building"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoin))

Get them while they're hot!

Comment: Awh, I was mislead because I thought the first one was rot13(DHRRA), but couldn't find a definition that would match :x