# Vowelburger™ Inside-Out Burger

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418) and Ébe Isaac's [Double Supreme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94590/vowelburger-double-supreme-1) Riddle.</sup>

The local Vowelburgers™ has added a new item to their ever-expanding menu, the Inside-Out Burger! This peculiar addition has the two patties on the outside of the burger with the buns sandwiched in between!

Here is the new menu:

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ??? | loosen |
| ??? | wavy |
| ??? | inside |
| ??? | Peralta |

Can you identify each type from the menu's description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This week's Vowelburgers come with

> **N** and **D** buns

The burgers are as follows

> **UNDO** (loosen)
>  **UNDE** (wavy)
>  **ENDO** (inside)
>  **ANDY** (Andy Samberg plays Jake Peralta in Brooklyn 99, credit to Stiv)
>  **Original last guess**
>  [**ANDE**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alejandro_Peralta) (by Alejandro Peralta)

Comment: Your solution is very close to being correct, but your incorrect about one of the burger types. That was very fast though!

Comment: Pretty sure you want [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Samberg) for the fourth, as rot13(NAQL Fnzoret cynlf Wnxr CRENYGN va Oebbxyla 99)

Comment: Congrats! I allowed the Y to be in use because in that case it's being used as a vowel sound.

Comment: @aguy No problem, good puzzle!