# Vowelburgers™ from other cuisines

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
The local Vowelburgers™ restaurant, always looking for inspiration, decided to take a look at some other cuisines for their new menu.

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ? | so |
| ? | this |
| ? | metal |
| ? | your |
| ? | do |

Can you help me identify each one from the description on the menu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the patties are

> T and N

and the burgers are

> a Catalan TAN meaning "so", a Polish TEN meaning "this", an English TIN meaning a kind of metal, a French TON meaning "your", and a German TUN meaning "do".

OP informs me in comments that "other cuisines" means that *every single* one of these is supposed to be not-English, so I remark that

> TIN means tin not only in English but also in Afrikaans, Danish, Dutch, Faroese, and Icelandic, and also means corrugated iron in Atong.

Comment: 'bgure' phvfvarf zrnaf ab Ratyvfu :)

Comment: Pbhyq nyfb qb gva va Qnavfu be gha va Jryfu