# Not a Vowelburger, but what is it?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

*<sup>Inspired by the original [Vowelburger riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/5373).</sup>*
A competitor has appeared to the Vowelburgers restaurant! Can you tell what they're doing?

| Patty | ??? |
| --- | --- |
| ? | I |
| ? | metal |
| ? | song |
| ? | money |

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Consonant burgers with vowel buns (O, E).

---

> I = one 
>  metal = ore 
>  song = ode 
>  money = owe

Comment: Yep, you got it.