# Vowelburger™ Bread-lover's Double Supreme

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418).</sup>

*Vowelburgers™* has decided to start changing things up a bit for bread connoisseurs and they have started making the *Bread-lover's Double Supreme* with two consonant buns on the top, two consonant buns on the bottom, and two vowel patties sandwiched in between. The patties are the same in every burger, but each burger will have a different combination of buns.

Here is their menu:

| Buns | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ??, ?? | hole |
| ??, ?? | draft |
| ??, ?? | cover |
| ??, ?? | wash out |
| ??, ?? | circle |
| ??, ?? | imagined |
| ??, ?? | t̶h̶i̶c̶k̶e̶t̶ |

Can you identify each type from the description on the menu?

Comment: How strict is the "different combination of buns" rule? Do you mean that no two buns are the same? Or do you mean two burgers can share one bun, with the other bun being different (i.e. BAT & CAT share a T, but have a "different combination")?

Comment: @Alconja You can use the same buns twice within the same word or across multiple words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vowel-patties are

> E and A.

The words are

> BREACH hole, BREATH draft, SHEATH cover, BLEACH wash out, WREATH circle, DREAMT imagined, and QUEACH thicket. (That has a vowel in one of the buns, but OP has confirmed that it was the intended word.)

Comment: rot13(DHRNPU) was the one I was thinking about, but you are correct, that it contains a vowel in the bun which I didn't notice. Your other six are exactly the ones I was thinking of.

Comment: Two consonant* buns ... (* for some value of consonant)