# Vozzellbaugor™ Surprise Fries

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
I’ve opened a new French restaurant named Vozzellbaugor™, an entirely original and unstolen idea. My restaurant has come out with a new line of food called Surprise Fries: french fry burgers with two secret ingredients. Can you detect my delectable delights?

| Secrets | Vozzellbaugor™ Surprise Fries |
| --- | --- |
| ?? | cloth |
| ?? | cloak |
| ?? | prescription |
| ?? | election |
| ?? | Einstein |

Comment: I'm not sure, but I _think_ white can mate in four.

Comment: But is this position reachable in a legal game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Today's Vozzellbaugor Surprise Fries comes with:

> A **P** bun and an **L** bun, with a **vowel-and-L** filling:
>
>  AL - "cloth", i.e **PALL** ([a cover for a coffin](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pall))
>  EL - "cloak", i.e. **PELL** ([a fur-lined cloak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pell))
>  IL - "prescription", i.e. **PILL**
>  OL - "election", i.e. **POLL**
>  UL - "Einstein", i.e. **PULL** (a remark on the gravitational *pull* of a Black Hole, one of Einstein's key areas of research)

Hang on, wait - there seems to be some kind of raid going on?! Oh gosh, it's those Vowelburger guys from up the street! I'm going to make myself scarce...

Comment: Thanks for being a loyal customer! Do you wish to help contribute support to us in an unfair lawsuit created by that monster Vowelburger food chain? You did find our delights rather fast!

Comment: Judge, I have evidence of slander, premised on the fact that we win this case!