# Vowelburgers™ for the Workers

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sub>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/28719).</sub>*

---

Another Vowelburgers™ restaurant is open! Their specialty? The burgers are specially made for specific occupations!

While they are pretty simple: **bun**, **meat**, another **bun**; please give them a bite!

| Meat | Vowelburger™'s Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| A | Bodybuilders |
| E | Singers |
| I | Writers |
| O | Auctioneers |
| U | Programmers |

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These burgers seem to have

> **L** and **T** buns

They serve their respective occupations thusly:

**Bodybuilders**

> L**A**T - for the [latissimus dorsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latissimus_dorsi_muscle) muscles, commonly known as *the lats*, especially among bodybuilders

**Singers**

> L**E**T - Barely possibly, short for 'Live Entertainment Tax', imposed on performances by live musicians for in-person audiences.  (*I have no better ideas, but the others fit too well for this pattern to be an accident*)

**Writers**

> L**I**T - short, of course, for Literature

**Auctioneers**

> L**O**T - what an item up for auction is called

**Programmers**

> L**U**T - short for [Lookup Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) (as seen on the Wikipedia page, in the section about "Hardware LUTs")

Comment: I’ve been at this for a while, this has to be it!

Comment: I have to admit that... for the singers... it goes...

Comment: (anw this is correct, well done! the previous comment of mine means.. rot13(yrg vg tb) apparently.. yeah I wasn't satisfied either lol)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not hugely confident, but I think a lot of the clues fit. The buns for these vowelburgers are brought to you by the letters

> B and G

**Bodybuilders**

> BAG - as in a punching bag, common way to build muscle

**Singers**

> BEG - often songs are begging for reconciliation or a relationship

**Writers**

> BIG - many aspiring writers looking for their big break.

**Auctioneers**

> BOG - As in [bog auctions - the online real estate auction platform](https://www.bog-auctions.com/en/home)

**Programmers**

> BUG - Do I really need to go into it? A joy many of us have faced.

Comment: Ah, not what I have in mind.. +1 anyway!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably incorrect, but worth a try. I think the buns could be:

> N and D

Bodybuilders

> [NAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide): nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide, a molecule that's apparently found in all cells so it literally "builds bodies"

Singers

> NED: several singers named Ned

Writers

> NID: quite the stretch, possibly stands for Network Internal/Intranet/Installation/other-computer-word-that-starts-with-i Drive which a computer writes to

Auctioneers

> NOD: you might nod at an auction to confirm something

Programmers

> [NUD: null denotation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/slib/Nud-and-Led-Definition.html)

Comment: Just as I post it the correct answer gets accepted! Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Partial, but I think the answer could be

> K and Y

The words I have defined are:

**Singers**

> Key - a singer should be singing in key.

**Writers**

> KIY - [The King in Yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_in_Yellow), a book of short stories by Robert W. Chambers

**Auctioneers**

> [Koy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/koy) - a slave, which would have been auctioned in the past.