# Penta-decker Vowelburger™

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
Vowelburgers™ is proud to announce the first ever Penta-decker Vowelburger™. This means six consonant buns sandwiching five vowel patties as shown:

[image: pentadecker burger]

Here is the menu's description of their first burger:

| Layer | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | passage 8 |
| 2 | poetry 7 |
| 3 | guide 9 |
| 4 | indirect 7 |
| 5 | rural 6 |

Can you identify what type this burger is from the description on the menu?

**Note:** The full name of the penta-decker burger contains layers 1-5 from left to right.

Hint:

> Eating the Penta-decker Vowelburger™ is like eating 5 regular* Vowelburgers™ merged with each other; in other words, the top of the first layer is the bottom of the next.
>
> *The word "regular" here means a bottom bun, single patty, and a top bun.

Hint 2:

> Each layer comes with lots of add-ons; those add-ons will be discarded, though, since we don't want the burger to get too high. From each layer, we extract only the simple Vowelburger™ from the bottom. (Note: the bottom is the left side of the word.)

Comment: I see lettuce and cheese too!

Comment: I had to count the buns! I didn't believe it!

Comment: I'm probably overthinking: but why is the 5th cheese not aligned with the others?

Comment: @Alto The cheese and Lettuce are not relevant to the puzzle

Comment: @Alto I have shifted the cheese around if that makes you feel better :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem correctly. Are the words we are looking for each the length of a regular Vowelburger, or are they the length of the numbers on the right half of the menu? If the former, what do the menu numbers represent, or is figuring that out part of the problem?

Comment: @LannyStrack I intended for that to be part of the problem to figure out, but since no one has gotten it, I plan to add more hints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> CORONAVIRUS (!)

*passage 8*

> CORridor.

*poetry 7*

> RONdeau, I suppose.

*guide 9*

> NAVigator.

*indirect 7*

> VIRtual.

*rural 6*

> RUStic.

**Feedback section:** the method of solution wasn't very clear until after the hints. At first I'd assumed we'd be looking for three-letter words each time, so I didn't get anywhere solving this. It was clear that part of the puzzle would be to figure out why there's a number together with each clue, but I didn't think we'd need to find a longer word and then cut out just part of it to make the Penta-Decker. My suggestion would be to clue this somehow *in the flavour text*, so that it doesn't seem so arbitrary. Something like:

> Making this new burger requires a lot of ingredients, each of which should be cleaned and processed before adding it to the burger.

Bonus: talking about "cleaning" the ingredients relates indirectly to the solution as well as referring to cleaning off the excess letters!

Comment: With a name like this, I don't anticipate many people will want to get it... Saying that, people are impressionable - as soon as one person gets it, I'm sure everybody else will too! ;-)

Comment: cleaning also reminds us to clean our hands regularly ;)

Comment: PS Agree with your puzzle feedback - I don't see how anybody could have worked this out without the hints, without getting a lucky break...

Comment: @Stiv Especially since the "poetry" and "indirect" clues are, let's say not the most obvious words with those meanings. Once you see the pattern you can fit it together and figure it out, but it would be a *very* lucky break to figure out that this fits without already having a strong hunch about the solving method.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's difficult to assess what information will be necessary and what will make it too easy.

Comment: @eyl327 Yeah, understood. That's why I [often](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22feedback+section%22) try to provide feedback as a solver :-)

Comment: @eyl327 Btw, what was the intended solution for "indirect"? Just for completeness.

Comment: Indirect was rot13( iveghny )