# Penta-decker Vowelburger™ #2

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
Yesterday, Vowelburgers™ announced their [first ever Penta-decker Vowelburger™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95085/penta-decker-vowelburger). They have made some simplifications to their manufacturing process and have created a new burger for today. A Penta-decker Vowelburger™ means six consonant buns sandwiching five vowel patties as shown:

[image: 1]

Here is the menu's description of the new burger:

| Layer | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | remove |
| 2 | money |
| 3 | god |
| 4 | rose |
| 5 | No.26 |

Can you identify what type this burger is from the description on the menu?

**Notes:**

> - The full name of this burger contains layers 1-5 from left to right.
> - Eating the Penta-decker Vowelburger™ is like eating 5 regular* Vowelburgers™ merged with each other; in other words, the top of the first layer is the bottom of the next.
> - There are no longer any add-ons in the burgers (not even discarded ones). Every layer is a regular Vowelburger™ *on its own*.
>
> <sup>* The word "regular" here means a bottom bun, single patty, and a top bun.</sup>

We hope you all will enjoy our new burger!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer may be

> POPULARIZED

*remove*

> POP

*money*

> PUL, currency in [Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_afghani) and historically in [parts of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C5%ABl_(coin)).

*god*

> LAR, [ancient Roman deity](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Lar-Roman-deities).

*rose*

> RIZ, [dialect word for rose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riz).

*No.26*

> ZED, the 26th letter of the alphabet.

This might fit with the first Penta-decker Vowelburger, since

> something that is popularised is often said to go VIRAL. (Perhaps a bad word to use these days ...)

A pedantic note:

> there seems to be an inconsistency here in which type of English is being used. American English spells the word as POPULARIZED but calls the letter ZEE; British English calls the letter ZED but spells the word as POPULARISED. It's possible there's another dialect (Canadian English) that used POPULARIZED and ZED, though.

**Feedback section:** this one was relatively quick and easy to solve, mostly because of the final clue. The number 26 is naturally going to bring one thing to mind, and (assuming we're OK with the pedantic note above) there are lots of longer words ending with those three letters. Then it's possible to work backwards: there aren't many 3-letter words ending with Z, and then there's a short finite list of 11-letter words ending with a specific five letters. The clued words are mostly quite obscure, but given the last one it's still doable.

Comment: Great job, that's the one I was looking for. As an American, I didn't think about the possibility of the answer having an alternate spelling (although it does make sense given similar words which have alternate spellings). The word rot13(MRQ), however, although not used here is something I was aware of.

Comment: You can use -ize in British English too; the Oxford University Press prefers that form to -ise. [EDITED to add:] On etymological grounds. As it happens, I agree with them.

Comment: As per your past feedback, I attempted to put some hints in the flavor text. In this case, I added synonyms of the answer ("simplifications" and "you all will enjoy"). Didn't think adding hints about the process would be necessary here since it's not too different from last time.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I wondered if you'd be along to mention that ;-) It's still true that BrE *largely* although not *universally* goes for -ise. And funnily enough the OP here is an *American* user of -ize and zed!

Comment: @eyl327 Yep, this time I understood the structure/process just from reading the question, without needing any additional hints. Didn't spot the subtle clues to the answer itself, but that's a really nice touch.

Answer (score 10):

Could the burger perhaps be

> REMOBILIZED

In that

> remove - "REM" being its first three letters;
>  money - is lusted after by the mafia/"MOB";
>  god - "BIL" is apparently the [goddess of the waning moon](https://historylists.org/other/bil-goddess-of-norse-mythology.html) in Norse mythology;
>  rose - "LIZ" Rose is a [famous musician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liz_Rose) (I find this to be a stretch in my answer);
>  no 26 - "ZED" is the British pronunciation of the letter Z, the 26th letter in the English alphabet

If so, perhaps the world needs to be this second Penta-decker Vowelburger™ as prudent recourse to the first one.