# Double-decker Vowelburgers™ -- 5 are meat, 1 is vegan

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
After making burgers with [five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95103/penta-decker-vowelburger-2) and [six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95144/six-layer-vowelburger) layers, Vowelburgers™ has noticed that the customers have not been hungry enough to eat such massive burgers. We are therefore introducing Double-decker burgers so you can get layered burgers in smaller portions. Five of the new burgers are exotic meats, but one is just vegetables. A Double-decker Vowelburger™ means three consonant buns sandwiching two vowel patties as shown:

[image: 1]

Here are the menu descriptions of the six new burgers:

| Layer 1 | Layer 2 |
| --- | --- |
| rap | saint |
| double | heir |
| percent | fool |
| wheel | honey |
| crystal | boy |
| location | call |

Can you identify each of these burgers from their descriptions? Which is the vegan one?

**Notes:**

> - Each burger consists of a layer 1 and a layer 2 (in that order).
> - Eating the Double-decker Vowelburger™ is like eating 2 regular Vowelburgers™ merged with each other; in other words, the top of the first layer is the bottom of the second layer.
> - Both layers are regular Vowelburgers™ on their own.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think these words are

> actually describing food, or things that could be food.

---

*rap* + *saint*

> TAPIR (TAP = rap [on a door], PIR = Sufi master) - like tapir meat. Thanks @Stiv for the second half.

*double* + *heir*

> BISON (BIS = twos, SON as heir) - like bison meat.

*percent* + *fool*

> BACON (BAC = blood alcohol concentration or *percentage* of alcohol in the blood, CON = fool [as a verb])

*wheel* + *honey*

> CAMEL (CAM = wheel, MEL = honey) - like camel meat.

*crystal* + *boy*

> SALAD (SAL meaning salt crystal, LAD = boy). This is the vegan one.

*location* + *call*

> MACAW (MAC addresses, CAW = call). Thanks @El-Guest for this one.

Comment: #1 should be rot13(GNCVE) due to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pir_(Sufism)). Still no clue on the last one...

Comment: Last one I think is rot13(ZNPNJ) because of rot13(ZNP Nqqerffrf)

Comment: @El-Guest has the one your missing. I'll accept the answer if you add that.

Comment: @eyl327 Done. I think I somehow missed EG's comment.