# Six-layer Vowelburger™

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by [Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
Vowelburgers™ announced their Penta-decker Vowelburger™ [two days ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95085/penta-decker-vowelburger) and added to their menu [yesterday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95103/penta-decker-vowelburger-2). For today's burger, they decided to bring back in part some features of the first burger but still keeping the form of the second. A **Six-layer Vowelburger™** means seven consonant buns sandwiching six vowel patties as shown:

[image: burger]

Here is the menu's description of the new burger:

| Layer | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | J |
| 2 | dwelling |
| 3 | multitude |
| 4 | stone |
| 5 | canvas |
| 6 | diffusion |

Can you identify what type this burger is from the description on the menu?

**Notes:**

> - The full name of this burger contains layers 1-6 from left to right.
> - Eating the Six-layer Vowelburger™ is like eating 6 regular* Vowelburgers™ merged with each other; in other words, the top of the first layer is the bottom of the next.
> - There are no add-ons. Every layer is a regular Vowelburger™ on its own. **Some layers, however, may be shortened forms.**
>
> <sup>*The word "regular" here means a bottom bun, single patty, and a top bun.</sup>

We hope this burger will lift your spirits in this difficult time. Stay healthy! (We deliver.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> REHABILITATED.

*J*

> REH, an Arabic-alphabet letter which looks a bit like a Latin-alphabet J.

*dwelling*

> HAB, short for habitation.

*multitude*

> BIL, short for billion.

*stone*

> LIT, which apparently can mean the same thing as "stoned" in drug slang.

*canvas*

> TAT, meaning "*make (a decorative mat or edging) by tying knots in thread and using a small shuttle to form lace*" - which relates to canvas.

*diffusion*

> TED, meaning "*turn over and spread out (grass, hay, or straw) to dry or for bedding*" - I guess this is diffusing the straw?

Comment: Great job, that's the answer! Although, only #2 and #3 have the intended explanations, The other 4 are full words (not shortened forms),

Comment: @eyl327 Edited, but I'm still stuck on J.

Comment: Gur Nenovp yrggre 'eru' vf funcrq yvxr n W.

Comment: 'yvgu' vf n ebbg jbeq zrnavat 'fgbar', ohg V unira'g sbhaq n qvpgvbanel ragel sbe whfg 'yvg' juvpu nyfb unf guvf zrnavat.

Comment: @LannyStrack got #1. #4 Hint: Hfvat n fynat grez nf n flabalz sbe n fynat grez

Comment: @eyl327 Ah, I think I see. rot13(trggvat yvg ↔ trggvat fgbarq)

Comment: @LannyStrack Yep, you got it

Comment: @LannyStrack Oh thanks! I found the Arabic letter, but didn't think anything of it since it's the letter representing R, not J. And I know nothing about drug slang :-)