# Another phonetic Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, language, english, letters

*<sup>You can find the other Vowelburger™ Riddles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger+is%3Aquestion)</sup>*
I ordered 7 Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat only at the **linguistic restaurant** - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ??? | pallid |
| ??? | attained |
| ??? | during |
| ??? | ace |
| ??? | marbles |
| ??? | dwelling |
| ??? | Korea |

The buns are [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) and the meat is a [vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio), so the transcriptions of these Vowelburgers™ may not share the same consonants as they do in the regular Vowelburgers™ riddles.

You can write your answer using IPA or the English alphabet as you please; bon appétit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the buns are

> W and N

Solutions

> Pallid = WAN
>  Attained = WON
>  during = WHEN
>  Ace = ONE (or could be WIN)
>  Marbles = WHIN
>  Dwelling = WONE (or possibly WOON)
>  Korea = WON

Comment: Just realised [why this answer felt so familiar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/60644)! (I realise there are subtle differences in the question...)

Comment: @Stiv Oh goodness, well I've upvoted your answer there, had not seen that one.

Comment: I was racking my brains, thinking "I'm sure we've had one like this before..." so I searched through lots of recent ones to find it... had to go back quite some way in the end! You were quick off the mark, well done.

Comment: I remembered about the very first Vowelbutger riddle only after posting this question. I hope you like the phonetic variant.