# Unusual Vowelburgers™

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's [Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle) and the variations thereof</sup>*

I got these Vowelburgers™ on discount, and they have a little different mouthfeel than others.  Why is that?

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | Ink |
| E | Vietnam |
| I | [CENSORED] |
| O | Rugrat |
| U | Tsk |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Vowelburgers™ are made with

> two **T** buns

And they are:

> **TAT** - slang for a tattoo, which uses ink
>  **TET** - [Tết](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt) is also known as the Vietnamese Lunar New Year
>  **TIT** - vulgar slang for a breast (hence the censorship)
>  **TOT** - "rug rat" is slang for a child (or a tot), and the show ["Rugrats"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugrats) focuses on a group of tots
>  **TUT** - a similar noise to "tsk" to express disapproval

The discount/different mouth feel could refer to

> the fact that the two buns are the same. Eating a burger with two top buns would certainly feel different, and they could potentially save money by only needing to buy one type of bun?