# Vowelburger™ Downtown Brown

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay, pattern, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92931/18418)</sup>*
Business has been slow this past year. As such, we've decided to create and market a whole new burger for faithful customers. May I remind you, we still hold our grudge against the court. We had to get this one in through a loophole.

| Single, Meat, Double | Vowelburger™ Downtown Brown |
| --- | --- |
| ? | The 67% City |
| ? | company |
| ? | cucumber |
| ? | toys |
| ? | bland |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These Vowelburgers™ are made with

> **D** and **LL** buns

And they are:

> **DALL** - 67% of "**Dall**as", a city
>  **DELL** - [a computer company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell)
>  **DILL** - a type of pickle, made from cucumbers
>  **DOLL** - dolls are toys
>  **DULL** - synonym for "bland"

Not sure if the title is relevant, but the "loophole" might refer to

> the unconventional clue for "dall"