# Ordered Vowelburgers™ as many as possible

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, letters

I wanted to order [Vowelburgers™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=vowelburger%20is%3Aq&searchOn=3) as many as possible, and came up with one idea. But for the purposes of giving a puzzle, I'm concealing what the idea was.

Here are the Vowelburgers™ I've received, grouped in a particular way:

- Here are the ones with one patty: **kilogram**, **bog**, **fail**, **chaos**.
- Here are the ones that I'm unsure whether they have one patty or two patties: **baton**, **deer**.
- Here is the one with a colored patty: **code**.

But there is one group remaining, in which I found two Vowelburgers™. And... yuck! I wish I've never ordered them. Why?

Comment: In case anybody reading this is unfamiliar with Puzzling's "Vowelburgers", see Avi's original post [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle) and [the various follow-ons](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=vowelburger%20is%3aq&searchOn=3) that have ensued over the years...!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind these Vowelburgers™ is that

> they are Vowelburgers™ when spelled in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)

*Here are the ones with one patty:*

> These have a single short vowel.
>
>  *kilogram*: mass **/mæs/**
>  *bog*: moss **/mɒs/**, **/mɔs/**, or **/mɑs/**
>  *fail*: miss **/mɪs/**
>  *chaos*: mess **/mɛs/**

*Here are the ones that I'm unsure whether they have one patty or two patties:*

> These are long vowels and [diphthongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong), which are two vowels in one.
>
>  *baton*: mace **/meɪs/**
>  *deer*: moose **/muːs/**

*Here is the one with a colored patty:*

> This patty has [rhotic coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel).
>
>  *code*: [Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) **/mɔː(ɹ)s/**

*But there is one group remaining, in which I found two Vowelburgers™. And... yuck! I wish I've never ordered them. Why?*

> Although these could fit into the second group, I suspect OP has quarantined them because they sound less than appetizing.
>
>  mouse **/maʊs/** or **/mʌʊs/**
>  mice **/maɪs/**

Comment: rot13(Gur frpbaq tebhc vf "cbgragvny" qvcugubatf, naq gur "lhpxl" barf ner "shyy" qvcugubatf.)

Comment: Wow great solve +1…@DannyuNDos I think the knowledge tag should have been on this puzzle as I don’t think a lot of people are familiar with this system…